# Adjust the scale per each individual facet/plot rather than per plots w/ shared axes?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, scale, facet

I am using `ggplot2` to make a graph that includes 15 plots (attached) and the following command:

```
ggplot(metrics, aes(Time.step, Value, color=Distance_f))+geom_line()+geom_point()+facet_grid(Metric~Distance_f, scales="free")+
  scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "green", "blue"))+geom_smooth(method="lm")+theme_bw()
```

Given that the range of values in each variable is different I would like to be able to adjust the scale based on the values.

I've tried `scales="free"` and `scales="free_y"` which improve the display but they force the scale for plots along the axis to be shared.

What would be good way of making the scale different for each plot? (e.g. it's difficult to see the data on plot 1 on row 2).

Any advice would be much appreciated. Many thanks!!pls see image here: 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

you could use `facet_wrap` instead of `facet_grid`